# Node js post request body in Joi Validation Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Recently I am working with node js and [Joi a validation package for node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi). I send post data through [postman](http://getpostman.com/) using the body, no params. But in node js application the request body shows undefined. Here are the snips:

```
const express = require('express');
const Joi = require('joi');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => 'Server is listening on 3000');

app.post('/users', (request, response) => {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
        username: Joi.string()
            .alphanum()
            .min(3)
            .max(30)
            .required()
    });

    const result = Joi.validate(request.body, schema);
    response.send(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot body-parser

u can use the body-parser package

```
npm I body-parser
```

so u can use it, like this

```
const bp = require('body-parser')
app.use(bp.json())
```

or u can use from express to

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use this example

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Joi = require('joi');
const expressJoi = require('express-joi-validator');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const schema = {
    query: {
        name: Joi.string().required()
    },
    body: {
        age: Joi.number().required(),
        company: Joi.object({
            name: Joi.string().required(),
            role: Joi.string().required().valid('HR', 'Technical') //enum style validation
        }).required()
    },
    params: {
        id: Joi.number().required()
    }
}

app.post('/testapi/:id', expressJoi(schema), function(req, res){
    res.send('validated');
});

//error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.isBoom) {
         return res.status(err.output.statusCode).json(err.output.payload);
    }
});

app.listen('3000',  ()=>{
    console.log(`listening to 3000`);
});
```

Comment: if any query then go to this link https://ciphertrick.com/2017/08/14/request-body-validations-joi-expressjs/